# IONIC 2 Texto innerhtml

Tags: wordpress, ionic, api

estoy armando una APP con la API REST V2 de Wordpress e IONIC, la intensión es mostrar las últimas noticias de un sitio web. El problema que tengo, que si bien parece sencillo no puedo resolverlo, es que al mostrar el excerpt del JSON me muestra todo el texto seguido sin crear una segunda linea, y lo peor es que se corta con puntos suspensivos. La idea es que al poner el texto si no entra en una línea automáticamente continue en la siguiente linea, pero no entiendo porque no lo hace. El texto se agrega con [innerHtml], probe de ponerlo sin el inner y me pone las etiquetas de párrafo y continua con el mismo error de que el texto no baja a una segunda línea y se pierde.

No entiendo el porque de este problema, a alguién le sucedió?
GRACIAS

Agrego 2 imágenes a los efectos de mostrar lo que me sucede[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, comproba la clase que tiene el div, probablemente tenes un width: tanto, overflow: ellipsis, o algo asi. no sé mucho de css pero suena a que el problema esta ahí, no en el codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba con `style="white-space: normal;"`

```
<ion-card style="white-space: normal;">
</ion-card>
```